# Prevent Stretching of Terminal Background on MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, images, resolution, terminal.app

This may seem like a silly question, but I am modifying the appearance of the terminal application using the profiles menu on MacOS 10.14. I have a nice high resolution image that I have used as a desktop wallpaper in the past, and want to use it as the background for the terminal.

However, the image is stretched very dramatically depending on the width of the terminal window. The only width that it looks normal for is the full width of my screen. Otherwise, it is compressed horizontally to fit the entire image into the terminal window.

I've thought to modify the image such that it's only as wide as the default width of a terminal window for my profile, but when in fullscreen mode, the opposite problem occurs, and it is stretched to fill the entire width of the screen.

Is there any way to change the way the image is fit to the terminal window size, in the same way a desktop wallpaper can be displayed with the "Fill Screen," "Fit to Screen," "Stretch to Fill Screen," or "Center" options present in the Desktop and Screensaver menu of the settings?

I've searched through the Color and Effects menu of the terminal profiles section, and have not found anything. Ideally, I'd like to have the largest image possible, and display as much of the image as the terminal window has width, with no stretching.

Comment: [apple.se] would probably be a better place to ask about Terminal.app preference settings.

Comment: This is relevant in particular when styling Terminal windows for presentation purposes!